when the script abrupts another script
WHATWG spec has interesting step in prepare the script element algorithm:

Otherwise, immediately execute the script element el, even if other scripts are already executing.

What is that case? How does one script may pause of executing another script?

It's as if the contents of the second script were inside the first script.

@Barmar I understand it, but I want to know what spec says by that; what is real code of this, example?

I think the only case where this happens while another script is already executing is when a script does something like script document.createElement("script"); script.src = "URL"; document.body.appendChild(script);. The interpreter simply blocks until the script is received, executes the code it contains, then resumes where it left off.

@Barmar No, DOM-inserted script elements are non-blocking

@Bergi Of course, you're right. That's why you need to use a load event listener for code that depends on that script.

Given the constraints, it's a script that is not a module, does not have a src attribute, and is inserted during a script execution. I think the following example qualifies:


<script>
console.log("before");
document.write(`<script>
console.log("nested");
<\/script>`);
console.log("after");
</script>




hmm I was try to make the same example, except <\/script>. Why is it so important?

You mean omit it?

I mean <\/script>  instead of </script> in document.write

@MaximPro the "" char is used to scape spetial chars, and denotate that the following character "/" has to be taken literarly regarless of in context it might mean something else. Sometimes its considered a good practice, although here, as far as I can see, its not necessary, as the "/" in this context does not have a special meaning.

@DanielCruz  Try it without.. :)

@DanielCruz it does matter, test it without backslash

@MaximPro, Keigh I see, so it depends on the context of execution?. I was testing on the developer console of the browser and it works fine both with or without it. Sorry If I was missinforming :(

@DanielCruz  Yeah, I think it's the HTML parser and the JS parser fighting each other here, in pure JS it's fine.

@DanielCruz to be honest idk, why in the document.write you should write backslash, rules of the parser nothing say about that, at least I didn't see.

@MaximPro  The HTML parser it pretty dumb here, you have an opening <script> tag, it's matching the </script> , it knows nothing of Javascript, so knows nothing of template literals or string literals, it's just looking for </script>..  The escaping Bergi has put prevents the first <script> tag matching that inside the Javascript part.

@Keith how does the parser interpretate the <\/script>? it doesn't correspond to </script>

Ahhhh @Keith I understand, so the scaping is so that the HTML parser understand that the script tag does not close inside the string literal. Once js gets to parse the content, for him its the same "/" as "/" but its necessary to scape to prevent the script tag to be closed prematurely during the HTML parsing?

@MaximPro Yes, like Keith said, <\/script> is used so that the html parser does not interpret it as the closing tag of the outer script. The JavaScript interpreter will create a normal </script> string value from this code then, which gets written into the document. There are many ways to skin this cat, like using '<'+'/script>', the backlash approach is the shortest (and most underhanded). Pretty standard pattern from the olden days where loading scripts via document.write was common :-)

@Bergi Keith thanks, I'd delete my comment but then your comments would be out of context so Id just edit to point to read the comments below.

Edit: It does not allow me to edit my comment :'(  it seems it only allows to edit during a certain period after the comment


@Bergi precisely, when the analyzer looks at the input stream, it detects that its closing tag is in document.write, but document.write has not yet been executed. And thus the rest of the script becomes out of context.

@Bergi correct your answer, you've written "not parser-inserted" but it is "parser-inserted", otherwise the scripts would be executed sequentially

@MaximPro Actually I was thinking of avoiding the condition in clause 34.2., but I don't actually know how to create a style sheet that is blocking scripts. Also when is prepare the script element ever called for a non-parser-inserted element?

@Bergi it's simple just insert before script tag external stylesheet (stylesheet must be following). Non-parser case is when you insert script via append method (non-parser cases described here).

@Bergi by the way I found bug in chrome, script nesting level for nested script will be always bigger than 1 so it must be case with interrupting parent script, but if you insert external stylesheet before script in document.write you get execution of scripts sequentially, example, firefox in this case work correctly unlike chrome

@MaximPro I could swear I tried that - it didn't occur to me that it might be a browser bug! As for non-parser-inserted (inline) scripts, I thought they wouldn't be executed at all, but apparently I confused DOM append with .innerHTML and .insertAdjacentHTML so my experiment failed.

@Bergi when HTML parser meets <script> token, it sets for the flag of script element
the value already started to true, that prevents from prepare the script element, even when node script will be inserted in DOM after fragment parsing process, that's why innerHTML doesn't call script (added this comment just in case).
